# Performing dead code elimination / slicing from original source code in Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

**EDIT: The original question had unnecessary details**

I have a source file which I do value analysis in Frama-C, some of the code is highlighted as dead code in the normalized window, no the original source code.

Can I obtain a slice of the **original** code that removes the dead code?

Comment: Maybe a few more details could help better understand your question; for instance, when you say "I transform the original code", you mean, you manually do it? Or do you use some Frama-C option? Ideally, if you could provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with some parseable code, and the exact command lines used, that could help getting an answer faster.

Comment: @anol thanks for your reply. Maybe I gave even more details than needed and I confused the main point. What I really need is to eliminate dead code. Now when I execute frama-c -val I obtain the normalized code with sections highlighted in red (dead code). I was wondering if is there any way to obtain a version of the original code (no the normalized) without this detected dead code. I hope I am more clear now.

Comment: @PatricioInzaghi there are still two (somehow related) things that are not clear in your question: (a) What do you mean by _original_ code the code as written in the file without unrolling, or the code after unrolling but before normalization by Frama-C itself? (b) How do you unroll your loop, with or without Frama-C? I'm unsure whether anything is available right now, but some cases would be easier to deal with than others.

Comment: @Virgile the unrolled version is the input for Frama-C, that's why it is not really useful for the question. With _original_ I mean the unrolled code I first entered in Frama-C, not the normalized version that creates, for example, temporal variables saving intermediate results of functions.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: there's nothing in the current Frama-C version that will let you do that directly. Moreover, if your original code contains macros, Frama-C will not even see the real original code, as it relies on an external preprocessor (e.g. `cpp`) to do macro expansion.

Longer answer: Each statement in the normalized (aka CIL) Abstract Syntax Tree (AST, the internal representation of C code within Frama-C) contains information about the location (start point and end point) of the original statement where it stems from, and this information is also available in the original AST (aka Cabs). It might thus be possible for someone with a good knowledge of Frama-C's inner workings (e.g. a reader of the [developer's manual](http://frama-c.com/download/plugin-development-guide-20.0-Calcium.pdf)), to build a correspondance between both, and to use that to detect dead statement in Cabs. Going even further, one could bypass Cabs, and identify zones in the original text of the program which are dead code. Note however that it would be a tedious and quite error prone (notably because a single original statement can be expanded in several normalized ones) task.

Answer (score 1):

Given your clarifications, I stand by @Virgile's answer; but for people interested in performing some simplistic dead code elimination within Frama-C, the script below, gifted by a colleague who has no SO account, could be helpful.

```
(* remove_dead_code.ml *)
let main () =
  !Db.Value.compute ();
  Slicing.Api.Project.reset_slicing ();
  let selection = ref Slicing.Api.Select.empty_selects in
  let o = object (self)
    inherit Visitor.frama_c_inplace
    method !vstmt_aux stmt =
      if Db.Value.is_reachable_stmt stmt then
        selection :=
          Slicing.Api.Select.select_stmt ~spare:true
            !selection
            stmt
            (Extlib.the self#current_kf);
      Cil.DoChildren
  end in
  Visitor.visitFramacFileSameGlobals o (Ast.get ());
  Slicing.Api.Request.add_persistent_selection !selection;
  Slicing.Api.Request.apply_all_internal ();
  Slicing.Api.Slice.remove_uncalled ();
  ignore (Slicing.Api.Project.extract "no-dead")

let () = Db.Main.extend main
```

Usage:

```
frama-c -load-script remove_dead_code.ml file.c -then-last -print -ocode output.c
```

Note that this script does not work in all cases and could have further improvements (e.g. to handle initializers), but for some quick-and-dirty hacking, it can still be helpful.